# Connecting Neo4J Database to my Django App

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, neo4j, neomodel

I am currently working on a project in which i need to use Django together with a Neo4J graph database. According to the articles i read online i have to use the `django_neomodel` library to do that. But when i try to install `django_neomodel` through pipenv or pip i get the following error:

[image: Error message returned on installation failure of django_neomodel]

The above errors says a certain `geos_c.dll` file of the `shapely==1.7.1` library was not found. I don't really know how to start solving this issue. Thanks in advance.
NB: I also get the same error when trying to install just the `neomodel` library.

I'm using `python 3.10.4` for this project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time of writing, shapely doesn't seem to work with python 3.10. See [Issues installing shapely 1.8.0 on windows python 3.10](https://github.com/shapely/shapely/issues/1215) and [RLS: Shapely 1.8.1 release](https://github.com/shapely/shapely/issues/1290#issuecomment-1041865722).

In my projects, I was able to install neomodel using python 3.9, so please try using either python virtualenv or conda to create a virtual environment with python 3.9.

Good luck!